# how to control mui-autocomplete popup/component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Can anyone suggest how to control if the mui-autocomplete is "open" or not?
in other words, I wish toprogramatically control if & when an autocomplete's item list is displayed or not.
(  I would later also need to control scrolling )

mui-autocomplete has an "open" property,
if set to true the list of items is shown.

but it does not seem to work the other way around.
in other words, initially, I wish that the items are not shown, the component should be  "closed".
thus i set the state variable i provide the autocomplete open property to false.
when its false, the item list is never shown, pressing the "toggle" button does not work, and writing a valid value in the box does not work either.
it looks like when the property open is set to false it overrides most of the components functions.

can anyone suggest a solution ?

Comment: Please share your code to codesandbox and share a link here, So we can look into it. Theoretically it sounds too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wish to control the autocomplete component you need to store its open state somewhere and then manually give the component its control back using the `onClose` and `onOpen` functions as such

```
import React from "react"
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import { Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";

const options = [
    { label: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
    { label: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
    { label: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
    { label: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
    { label: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
    { label: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
    { label: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
  ];
export default function MyComponent() {
    const [open,setOpen]=React.useState(false);

    return(
        <>
    <Autocomplete
    options={options}
    open={open}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    onOpen={()=>{setOpen(true)}}
    onClose={()=>{setOpen(false)}}
    />
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" disableElevation onClick={()=>{
        setOpen((open)=>{
            return !open;
        });
    }}>toggle autocomplete</Button>
    </>
    )
}
```

the example above maintains the normal behavior of the autocomplete component while giving you control to open and close it elsewhere in the code.

Comment: thank you vey much Asim,

do you also happen to know if/how i can set the scroll location within the displayed items list?

Comment: You're welcome, I do not think you can set a scroll location and I am not sure why you would like this behavior. However, you can always try playing with the selected value or available options to guide the user towards a specific option.